# How to use clazy Qt linter with clangd

Tags: c++, qt, clang-tidy

I'm using *VSCode* with *clangd* language server. There is an option in clangd `--clang-tidy`. Is there a way to run [clazy](https://github.com/KDE/clazy) or clazy-standalone in an addition to *clang-tidy*? I'd like to see Qt specific warnings in addition to generic C++ ones.

Thank you.